# Elegir una pregunta de un ARRAY mediante RANDOM

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Tratando de seleccionar una pregunta mediante RANDOM de un conjunto de preguntas recopiladas en ARRAY, se trata de hacer un random después de contar las preguntas que hay, y llevar a la vista todas las preguntas en el array + en número de pregunta creada por random en el controlador. ¿Sería correcto?

```
public function show($categoria)
    {
```

Aquí consigo las pregunta en un array:

```
$preguntas=Pregunta::where('categoria',$categoria)->get();
```

Aquí cuentos las filas que tiene el array:

```
$contarFilas=(array_count_values($preguntas));
```

Aquí creo un número random:

```
$numPreguntaElegida=rand(0,$contafilas):
```

Aquí devuelvo a la vista el array de preguntas y el número random para sacarlo en la vista con Blade:

```
return view("pregunta", compact("preguntas"),compact("numPreguntaElegida"));
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

No es que no esté correcto lo que hiciste pero lo más óptimo si nada más necesitas de una pregunta random sería que hicieras:

```
$pregunta = Pregunta::where('categoria', $categoria)->inRandomOrder()->first();
```

Answer (score 1):

Solucionado. Se añade "->random(x)" sustituyendo la x por la cantidad de elementos que queremos que devuelva en array de forma aleatoria:

```
$preguntas=Pregunta::where('categoria',$categoria)->get()->random(1);
```